# Unable to switch to normal user in command line

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, root, lxterminal

I am using `Raspberry Pi 2` with `Jessie` raspbian release. I ran into a problem when i was trying to make vncserver start at boot. I followed the instructions present in [raspberry pi's website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) to start vncserver on boot. But after following the instructions specified, my raspberry pi's command line always stays in root mode.

```
root@raspberry pi:/home/pi#
```

I guess it was because of the command that's specified in those instructions which had - `sudo su` command. How do i get `pi` user back in the command line like this -

```
pi@raspberrypi~$
```

I tried with these [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=25345) but they didn't help.

**Update:**
I am using my mac to login into Pi and then start vncserver. Now,

- when i run command `whoami` in mac -> i get `pi` as output.
- when i run command `whoami` in pi console -> i get `root` as output. (I start vncserver in mac command line, then open vnc connection to work on pi console).

Any suggestions on what's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To return to the Pi user just type exit.

Comment: Tried that, but it switched to normal user temporarily. When i re-started my terminal, it had root user showing up again. Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur what is the output of whoami?

Comment: I get `root` as the output of whoami.

Comment: Are you perhaps running a saved session using screen or tmux?

Comment: I dont think so. I did shutdown and start my raspberry pi several times. I am not sure how its getting saved. Will debug it more.

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly what you have done, because if you followed the instructions there should be no problem. (I assume you have rebooted.)

`vnc` is unlikely to work, because those instructions are for SysV.
If you are running Jessie this should be started with a systemd service.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697

Comment: I did reboot my pi several times. I will try using systemd service and see if it resolves my issue. Also does `sudo su` command create any problem, because when i googled it i found that `su` command is used to switch user (In my case it got switched to root user). Thanks.

Comment: @GirishSortur `sudo su` (actually `su`) is the "switch user" command. Without a target it switches to root. Try reading `man su`. You seem to have (at least) 2 problems here. First fix login (delete all the files you created, or restore any you changed) before worrying about vnc.

Comment: I did that already. I removed all the files i created. But only thing i wasn't able to fix was switch the user back to `pi` from `root`. I tried most of the methods i googled, but none worked. Thanks