# TightVNC starts fine locally, won't autostart

Tags: vnc, headless, raspbian-jessie

I am a total linux noob and I am trying to follow the directions here: http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc to start VNC at boot.

I can type

```
sudo systemctl start tightvncserver.service
```

in terminal and tightvnc runs and I can use it fine.

In the guide it says to use to enable it at boot

```
sudo systemctl enable tightvncserver.service
```

From another answer on stackexchange I tried

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable tightvncserver.service
```

but it does not start at boot, my pi just starts normally and the vnc instance won't respond from a client.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add your start command to crontab to force it to start at boot.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Have you checked the file ownership & permissions? What does `systemctl status` show? I use the following http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697

Comment: Status shows that it is enabled. If I run systemctl disable tightvncserver.service then it shows disabled.

Comment: I attempted adding it to crontab for the pi user using `@reboot systemctl start tightvncserver.service` but it still won't start at boot.

Comment: oh and status also says that it is inactive (dead) right after reboot.

Comment: I started over following the instructions in the link @milliways provided and now I have working VNC, even if it reboots. Thanks!