# Unable to execute tightvncserver: No such file or directory

Tags: vnc, vpn, jessie-lite

I'm setting up my RPi 2 so I can run VNC from my Mac. I am running Raspbian Jessie Lite, and using this setup

http://www.brooksskybennett.cm/brooksskybennett/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Setting-up-VNC-on-Raspberry-Pi-for-Mac-access-4DC5.pdf.

Utilizing the last script for the tightvncserver file:

```bash
#!bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: tightvncserver
# Required-Start: $remotefs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remotefs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
### END INIT INFO
# The Username:Group that will run VNC
export USER=”pi”
#${RUNAS}

# The display that VNC will use
DISPLAY=”1"
# Color depth (between 8 and 32)
DEPTH=”16"
# The Desktop geometry to use.
#GEOMETRY=”x”
GEOMETRY=”800×600"
#GEOMETRY=”1440×900"
#GEOMETRY=”1280×1024" 
#GEOMETRY=”1920×1080"
# The name that the VNC Desktop will have.
NAME=”Rasp2_VNC”
OPTIONS=”-name ${NAME} -depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY}”
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case “$1" in
    start)
log_action_begin_msg “Starting vncserver for user ‘${USER}’ on localhost:${DISPLAY}”
su ${USER} -c “/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}”
;;

    stop)
log_action_begin_msg “Stoping vncserver for user ‘${USER}’ on localhost:${DISPLAY}”
su ${USER} -c “/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}”
;;
    restart)
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
esac

exit 0
```

If I then check

```
cd /etc/init.d
cat -v tightvncserver
```

I don't have any carriage returns (^M) in the file

EDIT:

I run the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tightvncserver
sudo: unable to execute /etc/init.d/tightvncserver: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions as to why I would be seeing the error: No such file or directory? I obviously can see it when using

```
ls
```

or

```
sudo nano tightvncserver
```

Comment: Are you saying you are only getting the error when running it without sudo?

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/tightvncserver start                                                             Apologies as I didn't make it clear. My fault on that. I'm running the above command.

Comment: you didn't what?

Comment: what is the output of ls -la /etc/init.d

Comment: @SteveRobillard I edited the question as it should've been. Sorry about that.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1148 Jan 10 16:47 tightvncserver

Comment: First the above details belong in your question not in the comments. The problem may be this line export USER=”pi” but the owner/group is root. What happens if you change that line to export USER=”root”? Or change the ownership of the file to pi by doing chown pi:pi /etc/init.d/tightvncserver?

Comment: the link to the tutorial is broken as well please edit and fix that

Comment: what happens when you run this sudo /etc/init.d/tightvncserver start which is the actual command in the tutorial

Comment: I changed as your recommendations: USER = "root", sudo chown pi:pi /etc/init.d/tightvncserver and they both came back with No such file or directory. I also changed the original question to represent that with the sudo /etc/init.d/tightvncserver start which gives the same error.

Comment: Did you do them separately or did you do one then do the second without reverting the first? you need to change the line back to USER = "pi" before doing chown

Comment: Valid question...Changed to USER = "root" first as per permissions. Same error. Then changed USER="pi" and then changed permissions as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should run `tightvncserver` manually at the command line and setup the passwords etc. Don't use any fancy scripts.

You should not be messing around with `init.d`. That is `SysV` and is obsolete.

If you are running Jessie and want this to run at startup this should be started with a `systemd` service. See:-
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697

This is the script I use to setup for access from my Mac.

Comment: Thanks for this. I followed the original thread and although I get no errors. Nothing happens. I thought I'd get a screen after the sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable vncserver@1.service? Also am I suppose to have anything in /.vnc/xstartup file?

Comment: @Architek1 I assume you mean `/home/pi/.vnc/xstartup` AFAIK this should be created. I changed one line `xsetroot -solid grey  -cursor_name left_ptr`

Comment: I do as I did a sudo nano /.vnc/xstartup and the file was empty. Somehow I get the feeling that this shouldn't be the case...

Comment: `open vnc://IP ADDRESS :5901` on my mac command line is what I was missing.