# Window Manager on Headless Raspberry (VNC)

Tags: pi-3, vnc

I am trying to install a window manager for Raspbian (not Lite) so I can use it with my headless Raspberry Pi 3. I connect using VNC Viewer.

I have followed the tutorial that I found in this thread but it does not seem to work.

[Should running VNC on Jessie Lite "just work"?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41920/should-running-vnc-on-jessie-lite-just-work)

My raspberry connects via VNC fine and I can use it.

When I type "vncserver" in the terminal or when I enable VNC I get this line

> "unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $display for x11"

I don´t know if it is related. As to my understanding I need to run an X server in order to have a windows manager.

I am quite new to all this, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you want help you need to say what you did to setup VNC

Comment: I used this guide https://hackernoon.com/raspberry-pi-headless-install-462ccabd75d0 . I installed Raspbian Stretch with desktop from the raspberry website. As said before, connecting to VNC works but I want to install some sort of window manager to move and drag windows

Comment: I got it to work! I started from scratch and I followed this https://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server It worked like a charm

Comment: Hi @VictorGilGarcia, I may have a similar issue as you (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90386/no-window-manager-for-vnc-connection), but honestly I'm not sure because I'm confused by the question: you write "My raspberry connects via VNC fine and I can use it", but then why were you trying to run `vncserver` if VNC was already working? Or did you have some problems with it? Maybe you can edit the question for clarity?