# Configuring Kali Linux Raspberry Pi 3 with VNC Server

Tags: boot, pi-3, ethernet, remote

Good day

I am currently trying to setup my Kali Linux Raspberry Pi 3 to:

1. Work through VNC Server on my laptop over an Ethernet cable.
2. Start VNC server on the Raspberry Pi setup on boot.

Unfortunately I have run into multiple problems though and have tried every tutorial I can find. My problems are:

1. When establishing a connection over VNC server, my laptop just shows a 
     blank grey screen with no raspberry pi screen. What am I doing wrong?
2. I've seen multiple tutorials where people change the raspberry pi        config.txt so that it opens VNC server on boot. Whenever I run the command for the .config file, it can't find it. I should also probably mention that it never ran any configuration screen when I started it up initially.

I have spent so much time trying to figure this out and really don't know what to do anymore. I appreciate any help.

Comment: *"I've seen multiple tutorials where people change the raspberry pi config.txt so that it opens VNC server on boot."* -> This is not possible so you have badly misunderstood something.  Please include a link to the one of the "multiple tutorials" you are referring to.

Comment: Here is a link: http://diyhacking.com/connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-display/, http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-up-a-VNC-Server-on-your-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS, https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/running-vncserver-at-startup, please do advise me if I'm understanding something incorrectly, it may be!

Comment: Search that page for `config.txt`.  It does not appear even once.  It does refer to a `/home/pi/.config` file, but these are not the same.

Comment: Alright, I see my mistake. That was a mistake in my question though. Could you please show me where I find this file though? I managed to download raspi-config but when opening it, it says that it's meant for raspbian. So, what is the Kali equivalent? Thank you!

Comment: I've never used Kali.  This does not make any of my previous comments any less true, however.   As a suggestion, if you want to travel off the beaten path it may benefit you to work your legs in by walking the well paved road for a while first.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I doubt that the question demonstrates sufficient understanding of Linux to make use of Kali, but nonetheless the following shows how you can start `vncserver` on boot. 
[Start VNC on Jessie at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697)

I have not tested this on Kali, but it works on normal Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Thank you Milliways, I appreciate it! I will try it, I am interested in learning about the tools that Kali has to offer - thus the interest in it.