# i wanted to use an android phone to dispose of a portable display powered over usb. But neither the ssh or the Gui are working>

Tags: usb, ssh, display, gui

So as I said, I do not have an actual display or monitor for my **raspberry pi 3**.
That's why I wanted to use  an old android phone (**htc desire 500**) as a display.

That for I followed a tutorial (very serious though) 
--> http://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/

I rigourusly followed every single step of it, but finally, as I started the vnc viewer at `192.168.42.42:1` , it never asked for my password.

It just continued to `connect` until the natural error dialog `error : connection timedout` appeared.
So Guys, if any of you has ever tried this, it would be really nice if you could help me  out, because without a proper  display i can't even begin my PI Project

Comment: first step to debug would be to ping your android from pi and vice versa, then telnet into it, and see if theres a VNC service running on Port 5900... my guess is that the tutorial misses a few steps regarding the configuration of the android device ip on the usb interface

Comment: have you enabled ssh using `sudo raspi-config` ?

Comment: no i didn't but thanks for the reminder 

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you posted is obsolete.

See [Start VNC on Jessie at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697)

Also the method of setting a static IP won't work see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: real thanks to you. i'm going to try it as soon as possible.