# VNC on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: vnc

I have been trying to install Tightvnc server on my Raspberry Pi3b, which is running Raspbian Jessie. In a ssh terminal session I typed: `sudo install tightvncserver`. It seemed to install and when finished I typed in: `tightvncserver:1` and it came back with "bad command". I also tried `sudo tightvncserver:1` with the same results. It is supposed to ask to enter a password. I didn't get to that prompt.

What do I do now? I want tightvncserver to start at boot after I get this working, if I can actually do this.

Comment: You need a space between the command and the display address: `tightvncserver :1`, not `tightvncserver:1`. Either way, Raspbian now comes with a RealVNC server licence (enable it through `raspi-config`) which is exceedingly fast.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian now comes with a personal licence for the commercial RealVNC server. Install it like this:

```
sudo apt install realvnc-vnc-server
```

It creates an icon in the menu bar, and you can set it up from there.

Alternatively, enable it in raspi-config.

Answer (score 0):

To install you need `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`.

See [Start VNC on Jessie at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697) for one way of doing this.

You may have followed the Foundation tutorial (I don't know why the Foundation hasn't updated its documentation for systemd).

I haven't actually run `tightvncserver` from the command line for years, but AFAIK `tightvncserver` is all you need to enter.

Comment: In the link "Start VNC on Jessie at boot" it states to create a file. How do I do this? Do I create it in notepad on my PC and then paste it or what?

Comment: You can use any editor on any machine. I would use `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` but there are thousands of different ways of doing it. You probably need to read some basics on using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I use x11vnc instead, due to some problems on other PCs (not the Raspberry Pi).  Do **sudo apt-get install x11vnc**, then create (**touch /etc/init.d/myx11vnc**) and edit /etc/init.d/myx11vnc and put in it:
[CODE] ---------------

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/myx11vnc: set up the vnc server
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          x11vnc
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs x11-common
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs x11-common
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO

set -e

PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin

COMMAND="/usr/bin/x11vnc"
NAME="x11vnc"
THISSCRIPT="/etc/init.d/myx11vnc"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions
if [ -f /etc/default/rcS ]; then
  . /etc/default/rcS
fi

if [ ! -e $DISPLAY ]; then
   export DISPLAY=":0"
fi

if [ -e /root/.vnc/passwd ]; then
   PASSFILE="/root/.vnc/passwd"
fi

VERBOSE="yes"

if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
   echo "Executing $NAME $1..." >> /var/log/x11vnc-boot.log
fi

case "$1" in
  status)
    echo "$0 checking status of $NAME..."

    if [ ! -z "$(pidof $NAME)" ]; then
       echo "checking..."

       x11vncPID="$(pidof $NAME)"
       onePID="${x11vncPID%%[ ]*}" # ensure only ONE pid!

       if [ -d /proc/$onePID ]; then
          echo "found PID = $onePID, so it's running."
          x11Link="$(readlink /proc/$onePID/exe)"
          echo "/proc link is $x11Link"

          if [ $x11Link = $COMMAND ]; then
             echo "$NAME is  RUNNING."
             echo "STATUS: $NAME is  RUNNING." >> /var/log/x11vnc-boot.log
          fi
       fi
    else
       echo "$NAME has NO PID."
       echo "STATUS: $NAME is NOT RUNNING." >> /var/log/x11vnc-boot.log
    fi
  ;;

  start)
    #x11vncPID="$(pidof $NAME)"

    if [ -z "$(pidof $NAME)" ]; then
       if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
          log_begin_msg "Setting up $NAME..."
          echo  "Setting up $NAME..." >> /var/log/x11vnc-boot.log
       fi

       # uncomment this if you have setup .x11vncrc correctly...
       #if [ -e /root/.x11vncrc ]; then
       #   if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
       #      log_begin_msg "Using .x11vncrc for $NAME..."
       #   fi
       #   ARGS="-o /var/log/x11vnc.log -display $DISPLAY"
       #   $COMMAND $ARGS 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
       #else
          ARGS="-norc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -shared -allow 192.168.1. -geometry 1900x980 -passwd MyX11VNCPasswd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -display $DISPLAY"
          $COMMAND $ARGS 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
       #fi
       if [ ! -z "$(pidof $NAME)" ]; then
          echo  "$NAME PID=$(pidof $NAME) started with $ARGS." >> /var/log/x11vnc-boot.log
       fi

       if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
          log_end_msg 0
       fi
    fi
    exit 0
  ;;

  restart|reload|force-reload)
    $THISSCRIPT start
  ;;

  stop)
#   :
    echo "$0 checking status of $NAME..."

    if [ ! -z "$(pidof $NAME)" ]; then
       echo "checking..."

       x11vncPID="$(pidof $NAME)"
       onePID="${x11vncPID%%[ ]*}" # ensure only ONE pid!

       if [ -d /proc/$onePID ]; then
          echo "found PID = $onePID, so it's running."
          x11Link="$(readlink /proc/$onePID/exe)"
          echo "/proc link is $x11Link"

          if [ $x11Link = $COMMAND ]; then
             kill -s SIGTERM $onePID
             # echo "$NAME is  RUNNING."
          fi
       fi
    fi
  ;;

  *)
    log_success_msg "Usage: $THISSCRIPT {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

[/CODE] -------------------

Next do **sudo update-rc.d myx11vnc defaults** so that the myx11vnc script will run when you do a reboot.

The following script (**startupx11vnc.sh**) should work for you as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  Start x11vnc the hard way...
#
#
if [ ! -e $DISPLAY ]; then
   export DISPLAY=":0"
fi
#
if [ -z $DISPLAY ]; then
   export DISPLAY=":0"
fi
#
COMMAND="sudo x11vnc "
ARGS="-norc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -shared -allow 192.168.1. -geometry 1920x1080 -passwd MyX11vncPasswd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -display $DISPLAY"
#
$COMMAND $ARGS 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
#
exit 0
#
```