# How to setup VNC on Headless Raspberry Pi3 to open full screen on restart?

Tags: vnc

I have a brand new Raspberry Pi3. I had it connected to an hdmi monitor when I installed it, and VNC worked great. I am planning to use it without a monitor, and now when I restart without the monitor, it's dimensions are tiny.  How to I get full screen in VNC even after reboot?

I'm using the default VNC Server that came with NOOBS:

[image]

Comment: Which VNC server do you use?

Comment: @techraf VNC Server 5.3.2

Comment: If you have not already setup for headless see:- https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-virtual. `RealVNC` is probably OK if you want to view the same screen on the Pi and your laptop (and use their proprietary viewer), but IMO `tightvncserver` is more appropriate for headless use.

Comment: @Milliways I'd be fine with a virtual desktop, if there was a way to automatically create them on reboot.  That isn't listed anywhere in that url, so I'm guessing its not possible?

Comment: I can't help with `RealVNC` (I find their instructions confusing). I use `tightvnc` which I start on boot. See [Start VNC on Jessie at boot](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697) to start `TightVNC`. You need to install `sudo apt install tightvncserver` (which replaces `RealVNC`).

Answer (score 1):

As you are Using the New VNC for Raspberry PI , Make sure you Have Latest VNC on your Client PC. then

1. open your VNC Viewer
2. Right Click on your Raspberry pi
3. Click Properties
4. Go to Options
5. . [image: Scaling to Fit to Windows or as you want]

Answer (score 0):

Got the following link and it will explain how to change the "config.txt" file to resize your VNC screen when using the RPi without a display.  I had the same problem and this fixed it.

https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/523/2/troubleshooting-vnc-server-on-the-raspberry-pi