# Change default (as in nothing plugged in) screen resolution

Tags: hardware, hdmi, screen, vnc, ubuntu

I will probably be using my Raspberry Pi (running Ubuntu Mate) for remote desktop, but not *all of the time.* Sometimes I will want to plug it into a monitor.
When it's not plugged into a monitor, I'd like it to default to 1024x600, and not the tiny 650-something by 420-something. This way I can use it comfortably via remote desktop.
However, and here's the catch: when it's plugged into a monitor (I **cannot** predict the resolution of the monitor), I want it to use that monitor's resolution. This means I cannot just force hotplug and set the resolution that way, because that will not respect the monitor's resolution.

Any ideas?

Edit: I am using x11vnc, which means that the resolution that is shared is dependent on the screen size of the existing X desktop, which is in turn dependent on the monitor (or default resolution).

Comment: I presume your real problem is using `VNC`, because otherwise the resolution is immaterial. You should clarify in your question. Depending on the VNC server, there should be settings for resolution.

Comment: @Milliways Do you mean that it is possible to change the perceived resolution of the screen using the VNC server itself?

Comment: Depends - some "share" the screen. You need to add detail of server, and what you have done to setup.

Comment: @Milliways Thank you for clarifying. I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with `x11vnc` (which is pretty useless on a Mac).

I use `tightvnc` which I start on boot. This enables you to set VNC resolution, but does start a new screen session, not share screens.

See [Start VNC on Jessie at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I really would prefer to share the screen, but if I have to, I'll do this.