# Error while running a tightvnc script on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: vnc, headless

I have used this script for tightvnc

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: tightvncserver
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start vnc server
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

case “$1” in
start)
su pi -c ‘vncserver :1 -geometry 1600×900 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565:’
echo “VNC Started”
;;
stop)
pkill Xtightvnc
echo “VNC Terminated”
;;
*)
echo “Usage: /etc/init.d/tightvnc {start|stop}”
exit 1
;;
esac
```

Then while running the following command 
    sudo update-rc.d tightvnc defaults

I am getting error 
    -bash: insserv:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.

> insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: missing`Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
>   -bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>   -bash: command substitution: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>   -bash: insserv:: command not found
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ insserv: missing`Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script`tightvnc'
>   -bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>   -bash: command substitution: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>   -bash: insserv:: command not found
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script`tightvnc'
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ^C
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ clear
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo update-rc.d tightvnc defaults
>   insserv: Script tightvnc is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
>   insserv: missing`Provides:' entry: please add.
>   insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: missing`Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: missing`Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
>   insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `tightvnc'
>   insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script`tightvnc'
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run a SysV script on Jessie.

If you want this to run at startup this should be started with a `systemd` service. See:- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697
[Start VNC on Jessie at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697)