# Launch tightvncserver at reboot using cron

Tags: vnc, cron

Starting tightvncserver manually from a terminal works fine.
To start it @reboot I am using crontab -e with the following command:

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

The path is correct, I tested it using `which tightvncserver`, but it does not work.
I am new to cron, so I do not have experience. What comes to my mind, that there is trouble with the users. Cron does not know, which user should execute this command.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697 - while this mentions Jessie it works with Stretch (or any `systemd` OS).

Comment: @Milliways: Thank you very much for your link. This line in cron "at"reboot  sudo -u pi /usr/bin/tightvncserver" works for me, but I am not really happy with it. Tightvncserver is an executable which is able to work without sudo. However, "at"reboot   -u pi /usr/bin/tightvncserver or "at"reboot  pi /usr/bin/tightvncserver, "at"reboot  /usr/bin/tightvncserver  do not work.

Comment: @Milliways: Edit: su is what I want. I only knew that su is used for root, but I was not familiar with its options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start tightvncserver at startup by adding the line into /etc/rc.local.

rc.local starts after all the services are up after the OS start.

[Here is rc.local](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) from Raspberry pi documentation.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to use cron. I something goes wrong, I have to replace @reboot with some interval of time, such that cron seems to be the better option for me.

Comment: @opens rc.local is your best option but if you want to use some other option, it will be your choice. As you have already mentioned you have tried to use cron but it did not function for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get it done with cron:

***sudo crontab -e***

add the line

***@reboot su - pi -c '/usr/bin/tightvncserver :1'***

This works flawlessly and doesn't come up with the "no pid" error.