# How do I start VNC on startup of Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: boot, pi-4, vnc

How can I run VNC on each boot?

Note: I use TightVNC server and Raspberry Pi 4 and Raspbian Buster

Comment: Do you use vncserver or Xvnc to start it manually?  If vncserver - do you use any parameters?  Any reason you are not using the default as that works and can connect over the Internet without opening ports (just interested)?

Comment: yes I use 'vncserver :1'  to start it

Comment: That's the only thing you enter from the command line to start it? No `sudo` required? Have you considered a `cron` job to start at boot - or a `systemd` service def?

Comment: yes. that is only thing I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you could do this.

Cron: 
You can edit the crontab by typing this in the terminal: `crontab -e`. Then you should add this line to it `@reboot vncserver :1`. 
Read the Cron docs here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Systemd (I'm not a 100% sure about the exact instructions but I think this is how you would do it.): 
Type `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/vncstart.service`. Add this to the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start VNC
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enter:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable vncstart.service
```

Read the systemd docs here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

After you're done with one of these reboot to check if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you **REALLY** want to use TightVNC server see:- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697

I wouldn't bother; The RealVNC included with *Raspberry Pi OS* is simpler and has many advantages.